# How do I change the config path for mysqld?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysqld

I want to change configuration file path from `C:\` to `E:\`, but I can't find the way to do this.

Alternatively, is there a way to start a new instance with the config file I want? I've done something like `mysqld --init-file="E:\db\my.ini"` but it didn't work as well.

--EDITED--

I started new instance with the config files, and it worked well, and I faced another problem. Could you give me a help for this one as well?

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100492/cannot-change-datadir-for-mysqld

Comment: Which version of Windows? Are you using a 'platform' such as XAMPP or WAMPServer? These have there own configuration files whicj may override the 'default' ones.I use XAMPP on XP. oi - stop laffin :)

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1, MySQL community server 5.6!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [--defaults-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_defaults-file) option as follows

```
mysqld --defaults-file="E:\\db\\my.ini"
```

or

```
mysqld --defaults-file="E:/db/my.ini"
```

If you are running MySQL 5.6 already on the Windows machine and you are trying to run an additional MySQL 5.6 instance, make sure you change the following under the `[mysqld]` group header in your `my.ini`

- the port number (other than 3306)
- datadir (such as `E:\db`)

perhaps like

```
[mysqld]
port = 3307
datadir = "E:/db"
```

**Give it a Try !!!**